# Converting Fortran to Javascript

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, fortran, interpreter, transpiler

I'm losing my mind with this Problem. I wrote an Interpreter and then a Transpiler to convert Fortran to Javascript. BUT every time I was stuck with the Problem of passing variable by reference.

As you know in Fortran there is no syntax different between pass by reference or pass by value, all looks the same. However in Javascript pass by reference can only work, if the variable passed in an Object.

Fortran example code:

```
REAL FUNCTION PYTHAGORAS (A,B,K)
REAL A,B,K
K = 12 // E <=> K in GEOMETRIE()
PYTHAGORAS = SQRT(A**2+B**2)
END FUNCTION PYTHAGORAS

LOGICAL FUNCTION GEOMETRIE (H,B,D)
REAL H,B,D,E
B = 12 
H = 7
// E is pass by reference, it's gonna be changed in PYTHAGORAS()
D = PYTHAGORAS(B, H, E) 
GEOMETRIE = .TRUE.
END FUNCTION GEOMETRIE
```

I did a lot of research, but until now, I didn't find any useful result.

I was wondering, if there's any library out there to do the Job (Client-side / NodeJS). I can't imagine that until now, nobody tried to lose this Problem before.

Comment: There IS pass by value in modern Fortran, but it is not important here. Can't you pass the variable in a list? Have you had a look at Emscripten? Asking for a library is off-topic here BTW.

Comment: of course there is pass by value in Fortran, as you can see in the example, the call of PYTHAGORAS(B,H,E) _// B and H are pass by value, but E is pass by reference._ 

I know Emscripten, but didn't try it yet. I think it will be more complicated to convert Fortran to C++ and then to Javascript.

Comment: No they are not, all are passed by reference. To pass by value you must use the `VALUE` keyword introduced in Fortran 2003.

Comment: that makes sense, I'm gonna try this way too. Thanks a lot @VladimirF
I'll come back for any changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lazy hack would be to systematically embed the variables passed to the functions into a JS object:

```
function PYTHAGORAS(obj /* A B K */) {
  obj.K = 12;
  return Math.sqrt(obj.A * obj.A + obj.B * obj.B);
}

function GEOMETRIE(obj /* H B D */) {
  var E;
  obj.B = 12; 
  obj.H = 7;

  obj.D = PYTHAGORAS({A:obj.B, B:obj.H, K:E}); 
  return true;
}

var res = {H:0, B:0, D:0};

GEOMETRIE(res);
console.log(res);
```

Output:

```
Object { H=7,  B=12,  D=13.892443989449804 }
```

That may work reasonably well in the hypothesis of an automated translation of the original listing, and the resulting JS code would be easy to compare with the original FORTRAN code.

Now, it's going to be unnecessarily verbose and overloaded, as opposed to a complete manual rewrite.

**EDIT : alternate version with truly separated variables**

```
function PYTHAGORAS(A, B, K) {
  K.val = 12;
  return Math.sqrt(A.val * A.val + B.val * B.val);
}

function GEOMETRIE(H, B, D) {
  var E = {}; 
  B.val = 12; 
  H.val = 7;

  D.val = PYTHAGORAS(B, H, E); 
  console.log('E = ' + E.val);
  return true;
}

var H = {}
, B = {}
, D = {};

GEOMETRIE(H, B, D);
console.log('H = ' + H.val + ', B = ' + B.val + ', D = ' + D.val);
```

Output:

```
E = 12
H = 7, B = 12, D = 13.892443989449804
```

Comment: the idee is great, but still not gonna work, because as i mentioned, E should be pass by reference and it will be changed in PYTHAGORAS as K (or obj.K). So before the return true; E should be 12 and not 0.

Comment: You're right. Please see the alternate version in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @Arnauld, the idee of obj.val it awesome! I'm gonna try your Solution.

Comment: @kamal where can we see your transpiler ?